# MKNetworkOperation failedWithError : unsupported URL

Tags: ios, url, network-programming, mknetworkkit, mknetworkengine

i just started using MKNetworkKit for my networking operations and i have tried to simply get some data from the server using these MKNetworkOperation but it rendered me a strange error .. really strange on which is : Unsupported URL , i searched a lot over this problem but no hope, i never tried this error before and i had an older app that use the same library with the same example without errors , look at this for error investigation :

```
   NSString *path =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"blabs.json"];
MKNetworkOperation *op =[[MKNetworkOperation alloc]initWithURLString:path params:nil httpMethod:@"GET"];
NSLog(@"%@",[op url]);
[op addCompletionHandler:^(MKNetworkOperation *CompletedOperation){
    completionHandler([CompletedOperation responseJSON]);
} errorHandler:^(MKNetworkOperation *CompleteOperation, NSError *err){
    errHandler(err,[CompleteOperation responseString]);
}];
[self enqueueOperation:op forceReload:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

`blabs.json` is not a valid url.That is why the error

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the non-ASCII characters in your URL as well:

```
NSString *path =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"blabs.json"];
NSString* pathEncoded = [path stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
MKNetworkOperation *op =[[MKNetworkOperation alloc]initWithURLString:pathEncoded params:nil httpMethod:@"GET"];
NSLog(@"%@",[op url]);
[op addCompletionHandler:^(MKNetworkOperation *CompletedOperation){
    completionHandler([CompletedOperation responseJSON]);
} errorHandler:^(MKNetworkOperation *CompleteOperation, NSError *err){
    errHandler(err,[CompleteOperation responseString]);
}];
[self enqueueOperation:op forceReload:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

If that file is inside your bundle then no need to use MKnetworkkit. Mknetwrokkit is for requesting from server instead of that you can directly get the content of the json file which is in your bundle. For getting the content of file you can write the code as

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResourece:@"blabs.json"];

This data you can directly use it and parse it.